# Coordinates of a Polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I select a Polygon of a layer in QGIS, I am pretty sure I can see its coordinates somewhere, but I have no clue where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or using the vertices tool after turning on editing

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you mean all the coordinates that make up the polygon boundary you can use the command geom_to_wkt in the field calculator:

```
 geom_to_wkt( $geometry )
```

That will return a Well Known Text representation of each polygon, ie. Polygon(43254.45245,4325435.435435) etc.

You can also select all features in the attribute table, copy them, and then paste them into Excel. With default behaviour in QGIS the first column in excel will then be a Well Known Text representation of the geometry.

[Edit] If you just want the centroid of each polygon, you can use the command:

```
centroid( $geometry )
```

That will return a WKT point with the centroid, ie. Point(34245423,4565645).

Comment: Sorry, but where is the field calculator and what does $geometry stand for?

Comment: You might have to work through http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html (and the rest of the manual).

Comment: How can I go from this Polygon(43254.45245,4325435.435435) to Polygon (lat long coordinates of each vertice of the poylgon?)